# Как находить временнЫе паттерны в данных?

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-обучение

В логе присутствуют события трёх типов: А и Б и Й. Записи просто две колонки: timestamp и тип ("А", "Б" или "Й").

Есть гипотеза, что определённая разнесённость во времени событий А и Б вызывает событие Й.

**Как найти на основе данных наиболее вероятный паттерн событий А и Б, вызывающий Й?**

Например, выяснится, что чаще всего событию Й среди прочего "шума" предшествовали события в такой маске:

```
-50 секунд: А
-35 секунд: Б
-05 секунд: снова А
 00 секунд: происходит событие Й
```

В обозреваемом окне времени 0..–50 с. встретятся и другие события А/Б, но они от раза к разу не попадают в устойчивый паттерн, и поэтому считаются шумом и исключаются из рассмотрения. Отношение сигнал/шум может быть очень в пользу шума. Величина рассматриваемого "окна" неизвестна. Лишь примерно можно с потолка взять, что оно "от 1 до 1000 секунд".

Временное попадание тоже не из мира целых чисел, а «приблизительно» с некой точностью. Т.е. паттерн можно считать одинаковым, если в первый раз первое событие А было в -50.01 секунду, а во втором случае в -49.52 Относительно размера окна в 50 сек, +–1 секунда точности – допустимое приближение.

Смутно догадываюсь, что нужно как-то применить преобразование Фурье и свёрточную NN.. Но я в этом полный нуб, нид хэлп.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, нашёл: [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) (KDE) – оценка плотности ядра ([ядерное сглаживание](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%AF%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). [Подробнее](http://ru.learnmachinelearning.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Для моей задачи нужно выровнять отрезки данных по событию Й и взять наибольшие пики в KDE событий А и Б. Подбора ширины окна и ядра – отдельный вопрос.